# Google Apps Script published add-on stopped working post chnages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor, google-apps-script-addon

I have a published Add-on in web store for Google Docs. I have also been able to make changes to it and re-publish to web store couple of times  in past.

But when I made a recent change to add-on, it won't allow me to test as Add-on again. Only error I am getting is:

"There was a problem testing the script as an add-on. Please try again later."

I see in Google's Issue tracker that such problems have been reported but for Add-on for Google Sheet where Sheet being tested was deleted was causing the issue.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763685

I have used different Apps script projects to test the code before copying it to published Add-on. Now I am not able to get Select Document screen either.

Same Apps-script project if copied and run as Add-on, it works fine, but not published version. Since this is already a web store published add-on, I need to make this version work.

Any pointers will be of great help. Thanks!